# How to change the SharePoint Quick Launch order In C#?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, quick-launch

In SharePoint client side object model using C# how to change the order of quick launch in site.

I need to get the landing page of SharePoint and check the order in quick launch and set the order to second position.

How can i do this using C#?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set order of quick launch order in C#.

Below code is to get all nodes of quick launch. You can perform your logic to set order of quick launch

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb xWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {
        SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = xWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
        foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Title == "Documents")
            {
                node.Url = "Your New Url";
                node.Title = "Your New Title";
                node.Update();
                xWeb.Update();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will have following options to set order.

**Add – Adds a new node after the specified node in the collection.**

**AddAsFirst – Adds a new node as the first node in the collection.**

**AddAsLast – Adds a new node as the last node in the collection.**

Comment: i want to add the node in between the node collection.The node it  should place second.

Comment: based on the node title how can i get the existing order ?